# Old Webcams Not Working

Tags: sound, usb, webcam

I recently found a small stash of old webcams I had lying around.  A Microsoft Lifecam VX-1000 and a Logitech Quickcam Express.  Both of them are recognized by Ubuntu (lsusb), but none stream video or audio.  Is there any way I can get them back up and running again ??

I know they are quite old, but why throw them out if they work.

I have been looking around for fixes but all of them are at least 10 years old, and I have not been able to implement them to get the cameras running.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Manolo

Comment: Do they show up in the `/dev/` tree? What's the ownership/permissions of the `/dev/video*` What does watching `sudo journalctl -f` as you plug in the cameras show?

Comment: I have one of these Logitech Quickcam Express there is no driver therefore it can not work.